# Cannot find the environment variable on skill deploy

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

​I am setting up ASK CLI on a new machine. I completed all the steps at Alexa docs and I am able to create a skill locally.

When I try to deploy it, it tells me: `[Error]: Cannot find the environment variable: AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID.`

I went and took a look at the credentials file at `~/.aws/credentials` and I can see that `aws_access_key_id` as well as `aws_secret_access_key` both exist. I checked with the CSV file and I confirmed that both those keys are correct.

What should I do?

I'm using WSL for Windows 10. I did setup on WSL for Windows 10 on my other machine and it did work.

Tried setting up a bash environment variable as well. Didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by removing my AWS credentials file. Then I reinstalled the ask-cli and reinitialized it using the `ask init --no-browser` command.